# How I can add a string value to a structure?

Tags: c, string, struct

I am writing a program about cards, but I can't add a string to the structure. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    char szin[100];
    char ertek;
} Adat;

int main()
{
    Adat pakli[52];
    int a=0;
    char szimb[13]= {'A','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','1','J','Q','K'};
    char szinek[4][100]={"pikk","kor","treff","karo"};
    printf("%s\n",szinek[0]);
    for(int b=0; b<4; b++)
    {
        for(int c=0; c<13; c++)
        {
            Adat d={szinek[b],szimb[c]};
            pakli[a]=d;
            a++;
        }
    }
    printf("%s %c",pakli[0].szin,pakli[0].ertek);
    return 0;
}
```

So, please help me, i searched a lot, but I didn't get any useful answer.

Comment: And what happens with this code? What errors do you get?

Comment: the printf give me a randomly character(it's wrong) and an A letter(it's good)

Comment: Since the longest suit name occupies 6 bytes (5 letters plus a null byte), you could change `100` to `6` without no obvious loss of functionality but using considerably less space.  You could even think about using a pointer to the name in the structure instead of an array (but on a 64-bit machine, that wouldn't save space — the structure would increase to 16 bytes because of padding, instead of using 7 bytes).

Answer (score 2):

I assume the compiler already warned you about this

```
        Adat d={szinek[b],szimb[c]};
```

because the compiler is going to try to do

```
d.szin=szinek[b];
```

and You can't directly do array2 = array1, because in this case you would manipulate the addresses (char *) of the arrays and not their values.

That's the proper way to initialize your char[] and your struct

```
for(int c=0; c<13; c++)
{
    Adat d;
    strcpy(d.szin,szinek[b]);
    d.ertek=szimb[c];
    pakli[a]=d;
    a++;
}
```

or in a better way

```
for(int c=0; c<13; c++)
    {
        strcpy(pakli[a].szin,szinek[b]);
        pakli[a].ertek=szimb[c];
        a++;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int c=0; c<13; c++)
{
        Adat d={.ertek=szimb[c],};
        strcpy(d.szin,szinek[b]);
        pakli[a]=d;
        a++;
}
```

or

```
for(int c=0; c<13; c++)
{
        pakli[a].ertek=szimb[c];
        strcpy(pakli[a].szin,szinek[b]);
        a++;
}
```